# Sum of integers returned fql

Tags: php, facebook, sum, facebook-fql, photos

This is my first post and I'm fairly new to php, mysql, and developing for facebook.

I'm having the worst time with this normally I would use the sum with the sql request but fql doesn't seem to support that. I'm trying the query the albums which works as expected, but I only want to **echo** the **number of total photos/videos.** I'm sure the solution is there I'm just not seeing it clearly.

===================================================

Currently I'm getting these results returned;

Album#1 = 50

Album#2 = 10

Album#3 = 25

etc.

---

I just want to add those #'s returned together.

===================================================

```
    try {
        $me = $facebook->api('/me');
        $fql    =   "SELECT photo_count, video_count FROM album WHERE owner=me()";
        $param  =   array(
                          'method'    => 'fql.query',
                          'query'     => $fql,
                          'callback'  => ''
                          );
        $fqlResult   =   $facebook->api($param);
        foreach($fqlResult as $row){
            echo "<br><br />";
            echo $row['photo_count'];               
        }

    } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
        error_log($e);
    }
```

=======================================================

Your help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  try {
        $me = $facebook->api('/me');
        $fql    =   "SELECT photo_count, video_count FROM album WHERE owner=me()";
        $param  =   array(
                          'method'    => 'fql.query',
                          'query'     => $fql,
                          'callback'  => ''
                          );
        $fqlResult   =   $facebook->api($param);
        $asset_count = 0;
        foreach($fqlResult as $row){
            $asset_count += (int)$row['photo_count'] + (int)$row['video_count'];               
        }
        echo "<br/><br/>";
        echo $asset_count;

    } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
        error_log($e);
    }
```